# How to describe a 90-degree down instead of up side down?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

In a scenario of a box, up side down is a 180 degree down. But, how to describe a 90 degree down? Such as fall down? Thank you!

Comment: By "90 degrees down", do you mean the box is lying on one of its 4 sides?

Comment: Yes, it is lying on one of it's four sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might say:

> The box was laying on its side.

> The box had fallen on its side.

> The box had tipped over on to its side.

Comment: Thank you very much!